# How to create a ticker function to keep track of new data entry in database with php

Tags: php

I have a question to ask. Is there any possibility to create a ticker form which it track for new data change/entry from database. Let say i have 3 table in my database which is Table 1, Table 2 and Table 3. If user change/insert data into the Table 1, the ticker form will show like "Table 1 had enter new data at 10:00am".

Can it be done with php and jquery? Please guide me if anyway to do so. Thanks and have a nice day

Comment: you would have to add a function to do this. unless you wanted to turn on the query log

Comment: @Dagon Any example of this function to be refer? As my skill is not that good enough yet, i'm new to the php. Thanks

Comment: A simple insert to track the other queries

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a thing as ticker function in PHP since it's just a scripting language & it's strictly depended on HTTP which is a stateless protocol. What you are asking can be done by combining different technologies together. I assume you are using mysql. Such as [mysql triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) & [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) etc.

First you can define a "trigger" to track db events logs. a sample query. (this trigger will insert a row into logs table when a samples row inserted)

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `test`.`inserted_samples` AFTER INSERT ON `test`.`samples` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
insert into logs (table_name, description) values('samples', 'a sample inserted');
END;
```

Then you can implement an XHR request with setInterval of Javascript. XHR request hits a php script that reads logs table by last update.

Comment: any demo on this technique? thanks and much appreciate

Comment: when i have time, i will make a demo & let you know.

Comment: Thanks and really appriciate your help. I need to learn from the basic. :)